# Array map with accumulator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How to use Array map with accumulator?

Lets have a list of numbers and find a list of current sums.
Example:

```
const nums = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1];
const sums = [1, 2, 3,  2,  1];
```

I try to do it with `map`, by using accumulator in a `thisArg` because according to: [MDN Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> `thisArg` - value to use as `this` when executing callback.

I provide an object with `acc` set to `0` as `thisArg`:

```
const actual = nums.map(val => this.acc += val, {acc: 0});

require('assert').deepEqual(actual, sums);
```

It crashes with error:

```
AssertionError: [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 ] deepEqual [ NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN ]
```

The test passes with an external accumulator:

```
let   acc    = 0;
const actual = nums.map(val => acc += val);
```

Comment: have you looked at Array.reduce ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Try using the reduce function instead off map it supports the accumulator out of the box.

Comment: How can be done with `reduce`? : `nums.reduce((acc, val) => acc.push(acc.last + val), [0])` fails.

Comment: cause there is no `Array.last`. you would need `acc[i]` or `acc[acc.length - 1]`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you loose [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the function, which is already set from the outer space.

You could use a [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) **and** `thisArg`.

```js
const nums = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1];
const actual = nums.map(function (val) { return this.acc += val; }, { acc: 0 });

console.log(actual);
```

For keeping a arrow function, you could use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the accumulator,

```
(acc => val => acc += val)(0)  // complete closure with callback
```

which works in two steps, first it calls the function directly with a value for `acc`

```
(acc =>                  )(0)  // function for generating a closure over acc
```

and returns the inner function as a callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
        val => acc += val      // final callback
```

with a closure over `acc`, that means the scope of `acc` is inside of the own function and inside of the returned callback.

```js
const nums = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1];
const actual = nums.map((acc => val => acc += val)(0));

console.log(actual);
```

Comment: Great to point out the lack of this binding but even better demonstrated the simplicity of creating closures with arrow functions.

Comment: This Haskellesque approach is real good if you "scan" an array to another one of the same size by iterating over items. Nice pattern.

Comment: This is a really cool pattern, and very well explained, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` instead. 
This will not require you to create additional closure for arrow function and provide accumulator as regular argument.

```js
const nums = [1, 1, 1, -1, -1]
const actual = nums.reduce(
    (acc, val) => (acc.push((acc[acc.length-1] || 0) + val), acc), []
)

console.log(actual) // [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

***Edit:***

If you concerned about performance, here is a [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/cur-sum-map-vs-reduce/) for comparison with your's and @Nina's options:

- `.map()` with standard function - 27% slower in Firefox and 5% faster in Chrome than `.map()` with factory function
- `.reduce()` is 94% slower in Firefox and 52% slower in Chrome than fastest of two above.
- **your own option** (with external accumulator) is **75% faster** than `.map()` with standard function!